# React adding data from api to array problem

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to add the data in array from api and I want print array
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0UX8.png)ay

Comment: can you put the code as a part of the question ? as well as share the response structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.then(res => {
    mapArrayi.push(res.data);
    console.log(mapArrayi[0]);
});
```